# What is the best way to model occasionally missing data in the middle of an object-relationship hierarchy?

Tags: oop

Say I have an object model in which A has a one to many relationship with B and B has a one to many relationship with C.  In some real-world cases, I do not know what instance of B is related to a given instance of C, but I do know what instance of A is related to the instance of C.  Is there a best practice for how to capture the relationship between the instances of A and C in those cases?  Should I explicitly model a one to many from A to C even though it is usually implicitly known via B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudo code:

```
class A
{
  array of B objects;
  array of CB objects;

  method AddCB(CB object)
  {
    add to array of CB objects;
    if (CB object contains valid reference to B)
    then
      try add CB.B to array of B objects
      try add CB.C to array of C objects in B (CB.B);
  }
}

class B
{
  array of C objects;
}

class C;

class CB
{
  reference to C;
  reference to B;
}
```